# Detect if mobile app was installed from Production Track or Beta Track in AppStore/Play Store

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a Mobile App for Both **Android** and **iOS**, both are built using Xamarin.

**Android** - The app is uploaded to the play store on the *Beta Track* and once testing is completed it is promoted the *Production Track*.

**iOS** - The app is uploaded to *Test Flight* once testing is completed a new release is created in AppStoreConnect, the build is set to the app currently in test flight and then set ready for sale (therefore showing in the Apple *AppStore*).

Is there a way to detect in the Mobile App if the App was installed from the Beta Track or Production Track in Play Store (for Android). And for iOS detect if the app was installed from Test flight or the App Store?

I also have 2 different WCF Web services that the mobile app connects to, one is the Beta services and the other is the Production services, these endpoints are hard coded in the app.

What I am trying to accomplish is when the app is installed from the Production Track/App Store then connect to the Production services endpoint, when the app is installed from anywhere else (i.e. Beta Track/Test Flight) then use the Beta services.

What I am currently doing is when the app opens the user is given the choice to pick between the 2. When it comes to doing a production release I remove this choice from the user and just make the app go to production only. I would preferably like the choice to be made based upon where the user installed the app from.

To be clear, the purpose of this is to build a single APK/IPA app that can be used for both Beta and Production.

UPDATE - There have been some interesting suggestions using the API to re-route the web services calls based on version number, but these still involve building separate APK files for Beta and Production versions of the app (which doesn't solve the question). As for what I'm trying to accomplish with Detecting installs from the Beta Track, it looks as though this is not currently possible.

Comment: Use versionCode for android to differentiate between Production Track and Beta Track

Comment: @RahulKhurana How will `versionCode` achieve it, as the ask is to change the domain on the same build at runtime?

Comment: @RahulKhurana unfortunately that means doing a new build of the app and uploading it to the play store again, this is what I currently do and would like to get away from.

Comment: You can get the `versionCode` with each API and then according to the version to the server index file. if the versionCode is for production track then redirect call to production URL else to the beta track URL

Comment: @RahulKhurana I'm not sure I follow?  Are you saying store the production mobile version on the WCF Services and if the mobile app connecting to it matches that then it should connect to Production services only?  it's a nice idea but creates more problems then fixes, like beta users will find they are connecting to production once you update the services.  I'd still like to keep that separation.

Comment: @Dizzy both Production and Beta track users will use the same API. On the server-side, it will change the call beta/production URL to get the result.

Comment: @RahulKhurana that's make sense, but this will still require 2 apks built?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's not possible as of now. But if you want to test your same android build against two different domain sets of API, you can make use of `content provider` approach. You can create a admin/utility kind of app, which will pass/update the domain in your original app through the use of `content providers`.

I followed the same practice in one of my product and its really cool.

Comment: I'm thinking you are right and that it is not possible at this time unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Might be a bit late for you, but that answer can still help others...

It is possible to find the installation source on iOS as such:

```
#if DEBUG
    // XCODE INSTALL
#else
    NSURL *receiptURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL];
    NSString *receiptURLString = [receiptURL path];
    BOOL isRunningTestFlightBeta =  ([receiptURLString rangeOfString:@"sandboxReceipt"].location != NSNotFound);
    if (isRunningTestFlightBeta) {
        // TESTFLIGHT INSTALL
    }
    else {
        // STORE INSTALL
    }
#endif
```

I still don't have an answer for Android though.

Comment: This does not work as of Dec 4th, 2022.